# Switch a Gradle-based Vaadin 22 app to Vaadin 23 beta

Tags: gradle, vaadin, beta, vaadin-flow

I am a *Gradle* newbie, having used *Maven* in the past.

I successfully established a Vaadin 22.0.5 project using the *Vaadin Latest - Gradle* starter project downloaded from [*Hello World Starters*](https://vaadin.com/hello-world-starters) page. The project successfully builds and runs using `gretty` > `apprun` in IntelliJ 2021.1 EAP Ultimate edition.

How do I alter the project to use the current beta version of the next version, Vaadin 23.0.0.beta2, as listed on the [Vaadin releases](https://vaadin.com/releases) page?

## First attempt

I changed the `gradle.properties` file which consists of this single line:

```
vaadinVersion=22.0.5
```

… to this:

```
vaadinVersion=23.0.0.beta2
```

I clicked the floating windoid, *Load Gradle Changes*.

I immediately see this error appear in the IDE’s *Build* pane:

```
Build file '/Users/my_user/IdeaProjects/GetJava/build.gradle' line: 11

Plugin [id: 'com.vaadin', version: '23.0.0.beta2'] was not found in any of the following sources:

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

## Second attempt

After receiving [Answer by cfrick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71108849/642706), I did the following.

If found this at the top of the `build.gradle` file:

```java
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { setUrl("https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-prereleases") }
        maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
    }
}
```

So I made no edits there, as seemed to be accomplishing the same thing as the first part of the Answer.

I changed the entirety of the `settings.gradle` file from this:

```java
pluginManagement {
    plugins {
        id 'com.vaadin' version "${vaadinVersion}"
    }
}
```

… to this:

```java
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        maven {
            url = "https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-prereleases"
        }
    }
    plugins {
        id 'com.vaadin' version "${vaadinVersion}"
    }
}
```

I changed the `gradle.properties` file which consists of this single line:

```
vaadinVersion=22.0.5
```

… to this, using `beta1` rather than `beta2` seen above.

```
vaadinVersion=23.0.0.beta1
```

After executing `Tasks > build > clean`, I get a `BUILD SUCCESSFUL` message.

But when I execute `Gretty > apprun`, I get the following error message.

```
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.vaadin:vaadin-bom:23.0.0.beta1.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/vaadin/vaadin-bom/23.0.0.beta1/vaadin-bom-23.0.0.beta1.pom
     If the artifact you are trying to retrieve can be found in the repository but without metadata in 'Maven POM' format, you need to adjust the 'metadataSources { ... }' of the repository declaration.
     Required by:
         project :
   > Could not find com.vaadin:vaadin-core:.
     Required by:
         project :

Possible solution:
 - Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html
```

Comment: Checking mvnrepository.com there does not seem to be a beta2. Can you try beta1 just to verify if it is working? https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.vaadin/vaadin?repo=vaadin-prereleases

Comment: @Avec Thanks. I tried `beta1` instead of `beta2`, but no go. See edits to the Question.

Comment: I assume you tried both available beta versions after you did some changes to your config. Anyways since the build is in place I think there is something else. Verify against one of these maybe. [Base  starter Gradle](https://github.com/vaadin/base-starter-gradle)(no Spring) and [base starter Gradle with Spring](https://github.com/vaadin/base-starter-spring-gradle/blob/master/build.gradle). I have minimal experience with Gradle and no experience combined with Vaadin. Hopefully someone with both Gradle and Vaadin experience will be able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Pre-release versions are released first in Vaadins own pre-release
repository.  You would have to add the repository if you need access to
releases, that have not yet hit the public repos:

In `build.gradle` expand `repositories` by:

```
repositories {
    // ...
    maven {
        url = "https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-prereleases"
    }
}
```

In the `settings.gradle` add a `repositories` block too:

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        maven {
            url = "https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-prereleases"
        }
    }
    plugins {
        id 'com.vaadin' version "${vaadinVersion}"
    }
}
```

Comment: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.vaadin/vaadin?repo=vaadin-prereleases

Comment: This solution did not work for me. I added details in a *Second attempt* section.

Comment: @BasilBourque I think you missed adding the pre-releases to `repositories` (you assumed `buildscript.repositories` already has it, but that block does not matter (IMHO the whole block there is useless in the starter))